# ¡ Problema para reemplazar una fecha por otra en un archivo de texto (con Java)?

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo de texto que le entra como parámetro a uno de mis métodos Java. Primero recorro línea por línea el archivo de texto en busca de la Fecha de Emision:

si la encuentra, extraigo la fecha de esa línea en una variable. Como siempre viene igual, sé que si la encuentra, tengo que hacer un substring(84,93) para obtener la fecha dentro de una variable y luego hacerle un replace() por una nueva fecha!

El tema es que el replace() no me está andando bien y no me cambia la fecha! Les dejo mi código para que lo vean:

```
public class DateFormater {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

           // Open the file
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/home/incentivate/Desktop/AC0121.TXT");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                if(strLine.contains("Fecha de Emision: ")){

                    String date = strLine.substring(84,93);
                        if(date.equals("6/08/2018")){
                        System.out.println("OK");
                        strLine.replace(date, "06/08/2018"); // regex  / cosa a reemplazar
                        System.out.println(strLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Close the input stream
            br.close();
    }
```

En el segundo if entra bien porque me imprime el "OK", pero cuando imprimo la línea (strLine) para ver si hizo el replace() veo que no lo hizo. ¿Que puede estar pasando ?

Básicamente lo que necesito es anteponerle un 0 (cero) delante de la fecha que viene en el archivo de texto.

Ejemplo: Si la fecha viene así: 6/08/2018 necesito que se vea así: 06/08/2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar algo diferente, por ejemplo en vez de remplazar puedes darle un formato especifico a la fecha:

```
public class DateFormater {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

           // Open the file
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/home/incentivate/Desktop/AC0121.TXT");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                if(strLine.contains("Fecha de Emision: ")){
//Aqui agregamos un formato a la fecha 00-00-0000
                    String date = strLine.substring(84,93);
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY");
   String dateString = format.format(new Date(date));
                }
            }
            //Close the input stream
            br.close();
    }
```

Comment: Es una buena forma la tuya ... te pregunto, ¿Porque MM lo pusiste en mayusculas?

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre MM significa Mes mientras que mm (en minúsculas) significa minutos en horas.

Comment: Genial ! Gracias por la info ... podrías editar tu respuesta para que coincida con mi código, porque no sé donde es que metés la parte de tú código !

Comment: Me tira un error de "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date"

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre prueba ahora men, no recordaba lo del String a Date

Comment: Gracias @demianrc !!! Te hago una consulta (ahora te acepto la respuesta), ahora que tengo bien el código, para cambiar las fechas dentro del archivo de texto que me entra por parámetro tengo que reescribirlo todo de nuevo o hay alguna forma de reemplazar solamente la fecha dentro del txt ??

Comment: Pues prácticamente tendrías que cambiar todo, sobre escribir el todo el texto con la fecha correcta Broder. Aunque creo que hay otra manera más rápida la cual solo agregas la variable al texto ya existente.

Comment: Gracias hermanito, voy a seguir investigando !! Gracias por la ayuda, te mando un abrazo desde argentina :)

Comment: De nada Broder me alegra poder ayudado en algo, igualmente men, un abrazo desde México.